# how do you clone a git Gatsby project and run it locally?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm familiar with cloning git projects.
But I'm struggling to clone a Gatsby project, https://github.com/MunifTanjim/gatsby-theme-dox,  and then run the website locally.

I run `git clone https://github.com/MunifTanjim/gatsby-theme-dox`

Then it downloads

I go into the correct directly, and I've tried
`gatsby build`

This works
then
`gatsby develop`

I get the following error:

```
ERROR gatsby <develop> can only be run for a gatsby site.
Either the current working directory does not contain a valid package.json or 'gatsby' is 
not specified as a dependency
```

I've also tried
I also cd into the `demo` folder and run the same -- I get it to run locally but with a 404 error...

Is it possible to run the demo of this gatsby project?

I'm quite new to Gatsby so trying to understand by starting with a prebuilt project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you clone the repository you need to install the dependencies. `cd` to the root of your project and run `npm install` or `yarn install`.

`gatsby build` and `gatsby develop`, like all Gatsby commands, must be run in the root of your project, where the `package.json` is located. Otherwise, it will throw an exception.

In your case, run the following in order:

```
git clone https://github.com/MunifTanjim/gatsby-theme-dox
cd gatsby-theme-dox
npm install #or yarn install
cd demo
gatsby develop #to build the site in development mode
gatsby build && gatsby serve #to build the site in production mode
```

I'd suggest taking a look at [Gatsby commands (`gatsby-cli`)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/) to understand what you are running.

Answer (score 1):

- `git clone https://github.com/MunifTanjim/gatsby-theme-dox.git`
- `cd gatsby-theme-dox`
- `yarn install`
- `cd demo`
- `gatsby develop` (you should see the main page in http://localhost:8000/) or `gatsby build` and when it ends run `gatsby serve` in the terminal (see the main page in http://localhost:9000/)