# Gatsby socket and commons.js error when loading website

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, gatsby

I've followed this helpful answer: [how do you clone a git Gatsby project and run it locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70412683/how-do-you-clone-a-git-gatsby-project-and-run-it-locally/70423133#70423133) to load up a demo Gatsby project on git.

But I get the following error:

```
localhost/:1 
        
       GET http://localhost:9000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):5 
        
       GET http://localhost:9000/commons.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

This is what I've done

```
git clone https://github.com/MunifTanjim/gatsby-theme-dox
cd gatsby-theme-dox
npm install #or yarn install
cd demo
gatsby develop #to build the site in development mode
gatsby build && gatsby serve #to build the site in production mode
```

Then I added a `404.html` page to the `demo/public` directory since I was getting an error on `gatsby serve`
But now, all I'm getting is a blank website with the error I indicated above.
I'm very much a beginner in Gatsby and I'd like to get this demo running on my local machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I added a `404.html` page to the `demo/public` directory since

The `/public` folder is the one that is automatically generated in each build from the code from the source (`/src`) folder. You must not place code there, otherwise, in each build, it will be lost. Take a look at the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-project-structure/):

> `/public` *Automatically generated*. The output of the build process will
> be exposed inside this folder. Should be added to the `.gitignore` file
> if not added already.

If you want to create a custom 404 page, you can create one by [creating a `404.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/adding-common-features/add-404-page/#:%7E:text=When%20developing%20using%20gatsby%20develop,see%20all%20the%20available%20pages.) file inside `src/pages`.

Regarding your main issue, the fact that the output spots a `localhost:9000` (port 9000) indicates that you used `gatsby build`, not `gatsby develop` (otherwise the port would be the 8000). Using the first one `(gatsby build`) you'll need to rebuild the whole site to see the changes while running `gatsby develop` you'll see instantly the changes you made (unless you change the data sources) because of the [hot reload feature](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/local-development/fast-refresh/).

Your issue appears because there's no `socket.io.js` file, so it throws a 404 error (not found).

I'd suggest:

- Refresh the cache by running `gatsby clean`
- Make sure the `yarn install` or the `npm install` finished without errors (all dependencies installed properly)
- Run gatsby develop
- Make some "live" changes and once you feel comfortable enough proceed with the following commands.
- Run again `gatsby build`
- Serve the site by `gatsby serve` (this will make your site live locally under `localhost:9000`)

More recommendations can be found in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3229).

I'd recommend you, as I pointed in [your previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70412683/how-do-you-clone-a-git-gatsby-project-and-run-it-locally/70423133#70423133), read the [`gatsby-cli` docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/) to know what you are doing in each command.